# Consulta Mysql - Pegar o próximo valor maior que 0

Tags: mysql, sql, select

[image: Preciso fazer uma consulta Mysql que me retorne o próximo valor que não seja 0 após zero]

Exemplo, preciso que a consulta me retorne esses valores circulados.
O resultado anterior era 0 (zero). O atual não. Preciso pegar o valor do atual. E listar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você garantir que não há "buracos" no seu campo `id`, então a solução abaixo irá te mostrar os resultados que você deseja:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela t
 WHERE t.Velocidade > 0
   AND (SELECT t2.Velocidade
          FROM tabela t2
        WHERE t2.id = t.id - 1) = 0
```

Ou, para o caso do campo `id` possuir algum "salto":

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela t
 WHERE t.Velocidade > 0
   AND (SELECT t2.Velocidade
          FROM tabela t2
         WHERE t2.id < t.id
         ORDER BY t2.id DESC
         LIMIT 1) = 0
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado amigo! Era exatamente isso ..